# Is it possible to configure Python interpreter to use matplotlib and/or scipy without prepending the class names

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, scipy

I a using a a python package (SloppyCell) that relies heavily on the use of python plotting tools within scipy and matplotlib. In this software they have used, on several occasions functions from these modules but have not specified the class from which they came. For example, they have used:

```
plot(traj.timepoints, result, 'k--', linewidth=3,zorder = 10)
```

which gives me a NameError.

I was under the impression this function would be part of matplotlib.pyplot, however they have not even imported matplotlib, only scipy, which suggests this 'plot' function is part of scipy. I have attempted to modify their module slightly by importing matplotlib.pyplot and running the code as:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(traj.timepoints, result, 'k--', linewidth=3,zorder = 10)
```

But I get the exact same 'NameError: global name 'plot' is not defined'.
This is even more unusual (to me) because when I use this function outside of SloppyCell this works fine.

The software obviously works for other people because they have published papers that use this code. Therefore intuition suggests that there is a way to get the python interpreter to recognize this (and other functions like it) without prepending the name of the class from which it came. Does anybody know if this is possible? Alternatively can anybody think if there are other problems that I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about "from matplotlib.pyplot import *" (which is not optimal, if there are name collisions). I'm always importing matplotlib.pyplot as plt and use plt.plot()

Comment: No, this did not work. I figured out that the script works in ipython but not in normal python. Would you happen to know how to get it working in normal python as well?

Comment: @sascha is correct. That's basically what IPython is doing (when told to do so by using the `--pylab` option). I think that you must have executed the wrong thing when you tried it. For example, when you changed the code to `import matplotlib.pyplot` and changed the call to `matplotlib.pyplot.plot(...)`, you say that you got the same `NameError: global name 'plot' not define` which you couldn't have if that line had actually executed as written. You might get a different error, but not that one.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've tried both 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt' and from matplotlib.pyplot import * but still no joy

Comment: In `ipython` try `plot??` and see if something in the code header tells you its source module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a plain Python 2.7, I can do:

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot
>>> pyplot.plot
<function plot at 0xb4fe35a4>
```

In `ipython --pylab` I can do

```
plot??
pyplot.plot??
```

meaning `pyplot` has been imported both by name and by `*`.  It does the same with `numpy` (`np` and `*`).

`import numpy as np` gives access to all of `numpy` submodules.  But with `scipy`, you have import them selectively (e.g. `from scipy import sparse`).  I'm not as familiar with `matplotlib`, but it looks like it follows the `scipy` model.